# Double inheritance causes metaclass conflict

Tags: python, django, database-design

I use two django packages - django-mptt (utilities for implementing Modified Preorder Tree Traversal) and django-hvad (model translation).

I have a model class **MenuItem** and I want to it extends TranslatableModel and MPTTModel, like this:

```
class MenuItem(TranslatableModel, MPTTModel):
```

but it causes metaclass conflict:

```
(TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases 
metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class 
must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases)
```

What is the solution this problem? I hope that I can use double inheritance.

Comment: Why do you need multiple inheritance? It's usually best to avoid it when you can.

Comment: Because MenuItem has translations (need extends TranslatableModel) and must have tree hierarchy (need extends MPTTModel).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7314847/194311

Comment: MPTTModel has metaclass MPTTModelBase and TranslatableModel has metaclass TranslatableModelBase. Just like the answer in the question that @jathanism linked to, you have to set your metaclass because Python doesn't know which base class' metaclass to use.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Triple inheritance causes metaclass conflict... Sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557407/triple-inheritance-causes-metaclass-conflict-sometimes)

Answer (score 5):

You might want to do the following:

```
class CombinedMeta(TranslatableModel.__metaclass__, MPTTModel.__metaclass__):
    pass
class MenuItem(TranslatableModel, MPTTModel):
    __metaclass__=CombinedMeta
```

This should give you exactly what you want, without any error mesages.

Comment: In this case then `MenuItem.objects` will be the translation manager. In order to add tree manager, it has to be added manually - `tobjects = TreeManager()`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the late answer, but it i think it'll help for people who have same problem. When you subclass `MPTTModel` and another class, make sure you put `MPTTModel` first, like this:

```
class MenuItem(MPTTModel, TranslatableModel):
```

Comment: This is [what the docs recommend](https://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/models.html#setting-up-a-django-model-for-mptt)

Answer (score 1):

Generally the answer of @schacki would work. However, django-hvad overrides many other manager/queryset classes under the hood, which makes integrating with django-mptt/django-polymorphic and friends impossible at the moment.

Take a look at [django-parler](https://github.com/edoburu/django-parler), which features a similar API and admin integration as django-hvad, but plays nice with other packages too. The table layout is identical, so you should be able to switch the packages easily.