# Metaclass error from Flask-MongoKit

Tags: python, flask, mongokit

I'm trying to assemble a basic login system using Flask, Flask-Login, and Flask-MongoKit.

Here's my `User` class:

```
class User(Document):
    __collection__ = 'users'
    structure = {
        'username': basestring,
        'password': basestring,
        'date_created': datetime
    }
    required_fields = ['username', 'password']
    default_values = {
        'date_created': datetime.utcnow
    }
```

When I connect the Document model to the database (`db.register([User])`), querying against the document (`db.User.one({'username': form.username})`) gives me this lovely error:

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

I don't understand this error at all, and I have no idea how to fix it. What's going wrong?

NOTE: I understand what a metaclass conflict *is*. What I don't see is how I've caused one: it seems to be triggered somewhere inside MongoKit.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276037/python-3-typeerror-metaclass-conflict-the-metaclass-of-a-derived-class-must-b) to see whether it works.

Comment: This is what happens when a class' bases are changed to something incompatible with what they were created with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that I was importing the class wrong (I was feeding the parent module to `db.register` instead of the class.