# How to implement an interface in a way that is compatible with static type checks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, interface, mypy, static-typing

I have two base classes, `Foo` and `Bar`, and a `Worker` class which expects objects that behave like `Foo`. Then I add another class that implements all relevant attributes and methods from `Foo` but I didn't manage to communicate this successfully to static type checking via mypy. Here's a small example:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    pass

class Bar(metaclass=MyMeta):
    def bar(self):
        pass

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x

    def foo(self):
        pass

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, obj: Foo):
        self.x = obj.x
```

Here `Worker` actually accepts any `Foo`-ish object, i.e. objects that have an attribute `x` and a method `foo`. So if `obj` walks like a `Foo` and if it quacks like a `Foo` then `Worker` will be happy. Now the whole project uses type hints and so for the moment I indicate `obj: Foo`. So far so good.

Now there's another class `FooBar`, which subclasses `Bar` and behaves like `Foo` but it can't subclass `Foo` because it exposes its attributes via properties (and so the `__init__` parameters don't make sense):

```
class FooBar(Bar):
    """Objects of this type are bar and they are foo-ish."""

    @property
    def x(self) -> int:
        return 0

    def foo(self):
        pass
```

At this point, doing `Worker(FooBar())` obviously results in a type checker error:

```
error: Argument 1 to "Worker" has incompatible type "FooBar"; expected "Foo"
```

### Using an abstract base class

In order to communicate the interface of `Foo`-ish to the type checker I thought about creating an abstract base class for `Foo`-ish types:

```
import abc

class Fooish(abc.ABC):
    x : int

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError
```

However I can't make `FooBar` inherit from `Fooish` because `Bar` has its own metaclass and so this would cause a metaclass conflict. So I thought about using `Fooish.register` on both `Foo` and `FooBar` but mypy doesn't agree:

```
@Fooish.register
class Foo:
    ...

@Fooish.register
class FooBar(Bar):
    ...

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, obj: Fooish):
        self.x = obj.x
```

Which produces the following errors:

```
error: Argument 1 to "Worker" has incompatible type "Foo"; expected "Fooish"
error: Argument 1 to "Worker" has incompatible type "FooBar"; expected "Fooish"
```

### Using a "normal" class as an interface

The next option I considered is creating an interface without inheriting from `abc.ABC` in form of a "normal" class and then have both `Foo` and `FooBar` inherit from it:

```
class Fooish:
    x : int

    def foo(self) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError

class Foo(Fooish):
    ...

class FooBar(Bar, Fooish):
    ...

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, obj: Fooish):
        self.x = obj.x
```

Now mypy doesn't complain about the argument type to `Worker.__init__` but it complains about signature incompatibility of `FooBar.x` (which is a `property`) with `Fooish.x`:

```
error: Signature of "x" incompatible with supertype "Fooish"
```

Also the `Fooish` (abstract) base class is now instantiable and a valid argument to `Worker(...)` though it doesn't make sense since it doesn't provide an attribute `x`.

### The question ...

Now I'm stuck at the question on how to communicate this interface to the type checker without using inheritance (due to metaclass conflict; even if it was possible, mypy would still complain about signature incompatibility of `x`). Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Support for [structural subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) was added by [PEP 544 -- Protocols: Structural subtyping (static duck typing)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/) starting with Python 3.8. For versions prior to 3.8 the corresponding implementation is made available by the [typing-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) package on PyPI.

Relevant for the discussed scenario is [`typing.Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol) as explained by the PEP [in more detail](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#defining-a-protocol). This allows to define [implicit subtypes](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/#terminology) which saves us from the metaclass conflict issue since inheritance is not required. So the code looks like this:

```
from typing import Protocol             # Python 3.8+
from typing_extensions import Protocol  # Python 3.5 - 3.7


class Fooish(Protocol):
    x : int

    def foo(self) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError


# No inheritance required, implementing the defined protocol implicitly subtypes 'Fooish'.
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x

    def foo(self):
        pass


class MyMeta(type):
    pass


class Bar(metaclass=MyMeta):
    def bar(self):
        pass


# Here, we again create an implicit subtype of 'Fooish'.
class FooBar(Bar):
    """Objects of this type are bar and they are foo-ish."""

    @property
    def x(self) -> int:
        return 0

    @x.setter
    def x(self, val):
        pass

    def foo(self):
        pass


class Worker:
    def __init__(self, obj: Fooish):
        self.x = obj.x
```

Comment: This is pretty good! When I first saw your question, I thought about Protocols (heard about them before) but I didnt have any practice with them, so didn't use them and wrote something to bypass metaclass conflict :) But they are really the most suitable for your case. Learned something new for myself from your answer, thank you!

Comment: Also, usage of Protocols fixes the issue with `x: int` in Fooish and property in subclass, which previously gave `error: Signature of "x" incompatible with supertype "Fooish"` with mypy.

Comment: @sanyash Actually the incompatibility error was fixed by adding `@x.setter` in `FooBar` (which I did in the above code example). Removing the setter and doing `Worker(FooBar())` gives the incompatibility error together with the following note: *"Protocol member Fooish.x expected settable variable, got read-only attribute"*.

Comment: If I use my metaclass-code with `x: int` in Fooish and both `x.getter` and `x.setter` in FooBar I am getting `error: Signature of "x" incompatible with supertype "Fooish"`. So setter doesnt seem to help in this case.

Comment: @sanyash Indeed, I just reviewed the answer to that other question you linked and it refers to a [bug in mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4125). So in general it should work by adding the setter.

Comment: As usual, people need to answer their own questions here... lol

Answer (score 1):

1. To get rid of `error: Signature of "x" incompatible with supertype "Fooish"` you can annotate `x: typing.Any`.
2. To make `Fooish` really abstract some tricks are needed to resolve metaclass conflict. I took a recipe from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13661237/9609843):

```
class MyABCMeta(MyMeta, abc.ABCMeta):
    pass
```

After that it is possible to create `Fooish`:

```
class Fooish(metaclass=MyABCMeta):
```

The whole code that successfully executes at runtime and shows no errors from mypy:

```
import abc
import typing

class MyMeta(type):
    pass

class MyABCMeta(abc.ABCMeta, MyMeta):
    pass

class Fooish(metaclass=MyABCMeta):
    x : typing.Any

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def foo(self) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError

class Bar(metaclass=MyMeta):
    def bar(self):
        pass

class Foo(Fooish):
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x

    def foo(self):
        pass

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, obj: Fooish):
        self.x = obj.x


class FooBar(Bar, Fooish):
    """Objects of this type are bar and they are foo-ish."""

    @property
    def x(self) -> int:
        return 0

    def foo(self):
        pass

print(Worker(FooBar()))
```

Now it is time to think do you really want to make `Fooish` abstract because doing `class Fooish(metaclass=MyABCMeta):` can have side effects if `MyMeta` does lot of tricks. For example if `MyMeta` defines `__new__` you can probably define `__new__` in `Fooish` which doesn't call `MyMeta.__new__` but calls `abc.ABCMeta.__new__`. But things can become complicated... So, maybe it will be easier to have non-abstract `Fooish`.

Comment: Using `x: Any` in the interface kind of defeats the usage of type hints here. The type of these attributes is important for `Worker` and I want to have them type checked, so any class that implements `Fooish` must provide `x: int`. Using `x: Any` doesn't communicate this neither to the type checker nor to developers. I agree that using ABC with inheritance becomes a mess, especially due to the ABC mix. That's why I tried using `ABC.register`. But using a "normal" class as interface mixin leaves the module with that instantiable mixin type which even passes type checks for `Worker(...)`.

Comment: @a_guest I agree that using `x: typing.Any` wastes the info that x is int. Asked separate question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58349417/how-to-annotate-attribute-that-can-be-implemented-as-property.

Comment: @a_guest maybe implementing `Fooish` as normal class but with `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): raise RuntimeError('Cant instanciate Fooish')` will work?

Comment: @a_guest got a nice answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58349527/9609843. TLDR: in `Fooish` instead of `x: int` implement a property (maybe abstract) with getter and setter.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the pointer. By trying to make the example code as compact as possible I completely missed the asymmetry w.r.t. getting / setting the attribute `x`. Doing some more research I just discovered that PEP 544 added support for structural subtyping allowing implicit subtypes (which doesn't require inheritance). I summarized this in a separate [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58367433/3767239), in case you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you might be able to add a `Union`, which basically, allows `Foo or Bar or Fooish`:

```
from typing import Union

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, obj: Union[Bar, Fooish]):
        self.x = obj.x

# no type error
Worker(FooBar())
```

With the following:

```
class MyMeta(type):
    pass

class Fooish:
    x: int
    def foo(self) -> int:
        raise NotImplementedError


class Bar(metaclass=MyMeta):
    def bar(self):
        pass


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x: int):
        self.x = x

    def foo(self):
        pass


class Worker:
    def __init__(self, obj: Union[Bar, Fooish]):
        self.x = obj.x


class FooBar(Bar, Fooish):
    """Objects of this type are bar and they are foo-ish."""

    @property
    def x(self) -> int:
        return 0

    def foo(self):
        pass
```

see:

- https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213

Comment: I also thought about using `Union` but rather as `Fooish = Union[Foo, FooBar]`. However this has the problem that all possible types need to be known at the time the module is parsed. Since the package acts as a framework, developers are expected to create their own `Foo`-ish types but registering them so they'll work with `Worker` isn't possible then (or is it? maybe with some refactoring of modules and specific import orders?). Thus users would get type warnings on their side. I quickly checked the issue you linked and this indeed seems like it could help, so maybe I'll have to wait for it.

Comment: Doing some more research I just discovered that PEP 544 added support for structural subtyping allowing implicit subtypes (which doesn't require inheritance). I summarized this in a separate [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58367433/3767239), in case you are interested.