# How to annotate attribute that can be implemented as property?

Tags: python, properties, typing, mypy

I am trying to make mypy happy with my type annotations. Here is minimal example:

```
class FooInterface:
    x: int


class FooWithAttribute(FooInterface):
    x: int = 0


class FooWithProperty(FooInterface):
    @property
    def x(self) -> int:
        return 0
```

To my human understanding everything is fine: both `FooWithAttribute().x` and `FooWithProperty().x` will return `0` which is `int`, no type errors. However mypy complains:

`error: Signature of "x" incompatible with supertype "FooInterface"`

Is there a way to tell mypy that everything is OK? Right now the only way I found is annotating `x: typing.Any` in `FooInterface` which wastes the information that x is int.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mypy is actually pointing out a legitimate bug in your program. To demonstrate, suppose you have a program that looks like this:

```py
def mutate(f: FooInterface) -> None:
    f.x = 100
```

Seems fine, right? But what happens if we do `mutate(FooWithProperty())`? Python will actually crash with an `AttributeError`!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 19, in <module>
    mutate(FooWithProperty())
  File "test.py", line 16, in mutate
    f.x = 100
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

To make mypy happy, you basically have two options:

1. Make `FooInterface.x` also be a read-only property
2. Implement a setter for `FooWithProperty.x` to make it writable

I'm guessing that in your case, you probably want to take approach 1. If you do so, mypy will correctly point out that the line `f.x = 100` is not permitted:

```
from abc import abstractmethod

class FooInterface:
    # Marking this property as abstract is *optional*. If you do it,
    # mypy will complain if you forget to define x in a subclass.
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def x(self) -> int: ...

class FooWithAttribute(FooInterface):
    # No complaints from mypy here: having this attribute be writable
    # won't violate the Liskov substitution principle -- it's safe to
    # use FooWithAttribute in any location that expects a FooInterface.
    x: int = 0

class FooWithProperty(FooInterface):
    @property
    def x(self) -> int:
        return 0

def mutate(f: FooInterface) -> None:
    # error: Property "x" defined in "FooInterface" is read-only
    f.x = 100

mutate(FooWithProperty())
```

Approach 2 unfortunately doesn't quite work yet due to a [bug in mypy](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/4125) -- mypy doesn't correctly understand how to handle overriding an attribute with a property. The workaround in this case is to make `FooInterface.x` a property with a setter.