# How to declare a Protocol with a field which supports both a simple type and property?

Tags: python, mypy, typing, pyright

(Related, but not duplicated: [How to annotate attribute that can be implemented as property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58349417/how-to-annotate-attribute-that-can-be-implemented-as-property))

I want to create a `Protocol`, in which a field can be implemented by both a simple type and property. For example:

```py
class P(Protocol):
    v: int


@dataclass
class Foo(P):
    v: int


class Bar(P):
    @property
    def v(self) -> int: # ERROR
        return
```

But the code above doesn't type check. How should I fix it?

Note: I want to solve this issue without rewriting `Foo` and `Bar`, because `Foo` and `Bar` are not what I implemented.

According to [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/2072) the below code is not a solution because read-only `property` and a simple member have subtly different semantics.

```py
class P(Protocol):
    @property
    def v(self) -> int: # declare as property
        ...
```

Pyright denies this `Protocol` due to the difference.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In general, declare the `Protocol` using a read-only `property`, not a read/write field:

```py
class P(Protocol):
    @property
    def v(self) -> int:
        pass
```

This is needed because a read-only protocol attribute is satisfied by both a *read*-only `property` and a *read*/write field. In contrast, a read/write protocol attribute is satisfied only by a read/*write* field, not a read-*only* `property`.

---

As PyRight insists that fields and properties are different kinds of attributes, the attribute must be declared with both variants – once as a field and once as an attribute. For simple protocols, this can be done by declaring a separate field and property variant of the property:

```py
# field only
class Pf(Protocol):
    v: int

# property only
class Pp(Protocol):
    @property
    def v(self) -> int:
        return 1

# Either field or property
P = Union[Pf, Pp]
```

This is valid for both MyPy and PyRight.

Comment: As I mentioned above, this is not a solution. Because read-only property and a simple field are slightly different. For example: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/10797

Comment: In short, `property` is a class attribute but a simple field is not a class attribute.

Comment: `mypy` accepts the code in this answer fine for me. If you ask me, taking `type` of a thing whose static type is a protocol is the problem, not the fact that the property is implemented as a field.

Comment: @Yohei You asked for static type checking. Runtime behavior and static behavior are not equivalent. Static type checkers use classes and especially protocols to define instance behavior - they are not primarily concerned with how classes behave. The runtime type of a protocol instance is statically undefined and can be and do whatever it wants.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Ok, I understand. But actually, Pyright denies this solution because there are subtle differences between a simple field and property (see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/2072)).
I thought the difference which the author of Pyright author mentioned is that code, but this may not be right, and I may have you confused.

Comment: @Yohei Since Python types are not static, static type checkers ultimately apply a simplified model of how things actually work. For many things there is no "right" or "wrong" to this, since by design these models are not accurate. LSP says that a read-only attribute cannot substitute for a read/write field, but whether one treats fields and properties as equivalent attributes depends on the model resolution and goals (I personally find PyRight's stance impractical). I can try to come up with something that works for both MyPy and PyRight, though.

Comment: @Yohei I've added a variant that works for both MyPy and PyRight.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not strict about the type annotated for the property's getter, you could define `P` as:

```py
from typing import Protocol, Union, ClassVar

class P(Protocol):
    v: Union[int, ClassVar]
```