# python/mypy: how to declare ABC using value implemented both as property and attribute

Tags: python, properties, mypy, python-typing, abc

I have an abstract baseclass which uses a value whose implementation in different concrete classes can be either an attribute or a property:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Base(ABC):

    n: int

    
    def foo(self):
        ...
        a = ... + self.n

    @abstractmethod
    def bar(self):
        ...

class X(Base):
    def __init__(self, n: int):
      self.n = n

    def bar(self):
        ...

class Y(Base):

    @property
    def n(self) -> int:
        ...

    def bar(self):
        ...
```

The above code (outline, appropriately filled out), works at runtime, but mypy complains about the property in `Y`:

```
error: Signature of "n" incompatible with supertype "Base"
```

However, I can't remove the `n: int` because of `foo`, and I also can't put in an abstract property, because this breaks `X`. How should I declare the base class to make mypy happy with it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to annotate attribute that can be implemented as property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58349417/how-to-annotate-attribute-that-can-be-implemented-as-property)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Y` can't be less flexible than `Base` and be a subclass, so you're likely going to need to make `n` an abstract property on `Base` then add a setter to `X`. It's not pretty, but it works (I think, I haven't checked)

```
class X(Base):
    def __init__(self, n: int):
        self._n = n

    @property
    def n(self) -> int:
        return self._n

    @n.setter
    def n(self, n: int) -> None:
        self._n = n

    ...
```

Comment: Yup ... hmm... this is involved in a numerical computation, and wanted to numba.jitclass X eventually, but I realized that numba doesn't support ABC anyway, at least for the moment. When/if it does, I'll make "n" be a readonly property entirely... but your answer is correct for what I asked!