# Metaclass Resolver

Tags: python, metaclass

### Context

I started exploring the concept of Metaclass with python. Rapidly, I found myself facing a common problem.

`TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases`

From my understanding, this happens when you create a class [**C**] that inherits from two classes (or more) [**A**, **B**] that does not share the same metaclass [**M_A**, **M_B**]

```
M_A     M_B
 :       :
 :       :
 A       B
  \     /
   \   /
     C
```

The problem is well described [here](http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/%7Emicheles/python/metatype.html) and the solution is simple. We need to create a new metaclass [**M_C**] that inherits from both **M_A** and **M_B**

I tried to make this process automatic by creating a method that creates [**M_C**] dynamically. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41266737/4569526)

### My problem

My class [**C**] inherits from [**B**] and I want to use [**M_A**] has its metaclass, 
**M_A** is a custom metaclass (singleton)
**B**'s metaclass is abc.ABCMeta

My `metaclass_resolver()` successfully creates a new metaclass [**M_C**]
 however it inherits from `abc.ABCMeta` and `type` instead of inheriting from `abc.ABCMeta` and `M_A`.

```
from collections import UserDict

def metaclass_resolver(*classes):
    
    metaclasses     = tuple(set(type(cls) for cls in classes))
    new_metaclass   = metaclasses[0]
    new_meta_name   = new_metaclass.__name__
    
    #if there's more than one metaclass
    #combine them and create a new metaclass (M_C)
    if len(metaclasses) > 1:
        #get the name of each metaclass
        new_meta_name = "_".join(mcls.__name__ for mcls in metaclasses)
        #create a new dynamic class
        #               type('name','bases {inheritance}, attrs)'
        new_metaclass = type(new_meta_name, metaclasses, {})

    return new_metaclass(new_meta_name, metaclasses, {})

#my custom metaclass (singleton)
class M_A(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        c = super().__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        return c

    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        #When this metaclass is initiated, no instance of the class
        #using this metaclass would have been created
        cls.__instance = None
        super().__init__(name, bases, attrs)

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        #get the saved instance
        instance = cls.__instance
        #if the instance does not exists
        if instance is None:
            #create one
            instance = cls.__new__(cls)
            instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            #save it
            cls.__instance = instance

        return instance
    pass

#abc metaclass
class B(UserDict):
    def method_needed_in_C(self):
        pass

#my class
class C(B, metaclass = metaclass_resolver(M_A, B)):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print(type(self.__class__))
        #<class 'abc.ABCMeta_type'>
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = C()
```

In `metaclass_resolver()` when I use `type(cls)` it returns `<class 'type'>` instead of `<class 'M_A'>` which make sense since every class derived from `type`. But then, how can I point directly to `<class 'M_A'>`?

If I use `cls` directly I get this error :
`TypeError: descriptor '__init__' requires a 'type' object but received a 'str'`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should only use
`new_metaclass = type(new_meta_name, metaclasses, {})` and not ever
`new_metaclass(new_meta_name, metaclasses, {})` <- with this arrangement you are changing the metaclass of the metaclass - and you want the metaclass of the metaclass to always be `type` if you merely want to combine both metaclasses.

It is likely that on the unexpected input for abc.ABCMeta or even on your own `M_A` class, yo are getting this side-effect of only having one ancestor metaclass. That is probably the source of your unexpected behaviour.

In other words: to create your metaclass itself, call *type* not one of the metaclasses you are combining - even it this happen to work, the mechanisms in place that make those useful as "metaclasses" for ordinary classes are *probably* not useful and *certainly* outright meaningless for being a metaclass of other combined metaclass which include itself as an ancestor.

Another thing is that by using the `tuple(set(...))` thing for eliminating duplicate metaclasses, you are basically randomizing their order: metaclasses are a sensitive thing, and not all of them are built in a way they can be combined with others - and a lot less of them will be able to be combined in a random order. You can use a dict comprehension instead, which will both preserve the order and eliminate duplicates, and can extract the metaclasses name for your fancy naming in one step:

```py
def metaclass_resolver(*classes):
    
    metaclasses     = {mcls.__name__: mcls for cls in classes if (mcls:=type(cls)) is not type}
    new_meta_name = "_".join(metaclasses)
    return type(new_meta_name, tuple(metaclasses.values()), {})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! +1 for introducing me to [the walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html)

However, by using this condition : `if (mcls:=type(cls)) is not type`

My custom metaclass [**M_A**] will not be added to the dict since its direct ancestor is `type`. 


I could create a new class that inherit from my custom metaclass and check if 'type' is in  .__bases__ of this new class, but it seems a bit sketchy...