# How to call a method imported from another class without Metaclass error?

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, pytest, seleniumbase

On python 3.11, I'm trying to use a method from another class, like this:

**folder name:** *anyfunctions*

**script name:** *basicactions.py*

```
from seleniumbase import BaseCase


class Firstfunction(BaseCase):
    def login(self):
        self.open("https://randomsite/authentication/signin")
        self.wait_for_element("#username")
        self.click(".d-grid")
```

Then, I'm trying to create a test using Selenium with the following code:

**folder name:** *tests*

**script name:** *test_home.py*

```
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
from anyfunctions import basicactions

class AnyTestName(BaseCase, basicactions):
    def test_login(self):
        basicactions.Firstfunction.login()
```

That, I was expecting to run the login method, but the following error appears:

**TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases**

Am I forgetting to add something to call the class correctly?
Thanks

Comment: Calling the method isn't the problem. The class `AnyTestName` itself is not being defined. `basicactions` is a module, not a class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resolving metaclass conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276037/resolving-metaclass-conflicts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of the classic Page Object Model with `BaseCase` inheritance using SeleniumBase:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class LoginPage:
    def login_to_swag_labs(self, sb, username):
        sb.open("https://www.saucedemo.com")
        sb.type("#user-name", username)
        sb.type("#password", "secret_sauce")
        sb.click('input[type="submit"]')

class MyTests(BaseCase):
    def test_swag_labs_login(self):
        LoginPage().login_to_swag_labs(self, "standard_user")
        self.assert_element("div.inventory_list")
        self.assert_element('div:contains("Sauce Labs Backpack")')
        self.js_click("a#logout_sidebar_link")
        self.assert_element("div#login_button_container")
```

(Runs with `pytest`)

Comment: Thanks Mintz. In your example, considering the class MyTests OUT of the same script page as the class LoginPage, how can we call the method LoginPage() ?

Comment: `LoginPage` is a class, not a method. `LoginPage()` is a call to the constructor to initialize it. That class has a method, `login_to_swag_labs()`, where you need to pass in `sb` (The seleniumbase instance from `self` in the test), as well as the other arg that the method takes: `username`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to (nor can you) subclass `basicactions` in order to use it in the definition of the class.

You also need to create an *instance* of `Firstfunction` in order to call the `login` method.

```
class AnyTestName(BaseCase):
    def test_login(self):
        f = basicactions.Firstfunction()
        f.login()
```