# Metaclass conflict when separating classes into separate files

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

#### Edit

The problem was in importing. What I should have done was write: `from SomeInterface import SomeInterface`. Really I should write module name in lowercase `someinterface.py` as per [Python styleguide (PEP 8)](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

---

I have a file `model.py` the defines all classes related to my DB as well as instantiates my Base.

```
# model.py
metadata = MetaData()
DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()
metadata = DeclarativeBase.metadata

class Bar(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'Bar'
    __table_args__ = {}
    # column and relation definitions
```

The file `model.py` is autogenerated so I can't really touch it. What I did instead was create a file called `modelaugmented.py` where I add extra functionality to some of the model classes via inheritance.

```
# modelaugmented.py
from model import *
import SomeInterface

class BarAugmented(Bar, SomeInterface):
    pass

# SomeInterface.py
class SomeInterface(object):
    some_method(): pass
```

The problem I'm having is that for classes like `BarAugmented`, I'm getting the following error:

```
 TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
 metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

I only get this error when `SomeInterface` is in a separate file instead of being inside `modelaugmented.py`.

I understand that the metaclass for `SomeInterface` and `Bar` are different. The problem is that I can't figure out how to resolve this problem. I tried the solution suggested in [Triple inheritance causes metaclass conflict... Sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557407/triple-inheritance-causes-metaclass-conflict-sometimes) which works in the example given, but not in my case. Not sure if SqlAlchmey has anything to do with it.

```
class MetaAB(type(DeclarativeBase), type(SomeInterface)):
    pass

class BarAugmented(Bar, SomeInterface):
    __metaclass__ = MetaAB
```

But then I get the error:

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass 
bases multiple bases have instance lay-out conflict
```

Using SQLAlchemy 0.8 and Python 2.7.

Comment: yep... you're facing a problem of multiple inheritance. There will be another problem... In `BarAugmented`, what's the `__table__ ` it has to save the data to? Table `foo`? Table `bar`? Do you REALLY need this type of schema? (just asking, but it looks like a very complex structure for any ORM to handle properly)

Comment: @BorrajaX very fair points. I edited my question.

Comment: MHmm... It looks like the problem is not in SqlAlchemy... Take a look to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557407/triple-inheritance-causes-metaclass-conflict-sometimes and http://code.activestate.com/recipes/204197-solving-the-metaclass-conflict/ (I just found those links, I don't know if they'll be helpful) Could you try a non-declarative declaration? (just declare your table, then your class, then your mapping) ?

Comment: @BorrajaX thanks for the links. I tried them earlier but unfortunately  I get the error `'SomeInterface' has no attribute '_decl_class_registry'`.

Comment: Sorry about that **:-(** I'd go with a non-declarative, then. Doing the declarative model will probably alter your class `__metaclass__` (but wait for a real answer, though... you may not need to do that anyways)

Comment: I assume it is not the case, but if you need the same base class/interface for all your mapped classes, you could specify it as  a `cls` parameter of [`declarative_base`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/declarative.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base.params.cls)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there must be something I'm missing, because I created a similar file layout to yours (I think) and it works in my machine. I appreciate you kept your question short and simple, but maybe is missing some little detail that alters... something? Dunno... (maybe `SomeInterface` has an `abc.abstract` metaclass?) If you update your question, please let me know trough a comment to this answer, and I'll try to update my answer.

Here it goes:

**File `stack29A.py`** (equivalent to your `model.py`):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session

DSN = "mysql://root:foobar@localhost/so_tests?charset=utf8"
engine = create_engine(DSN)
Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
session = Session()

DeclarativeBase = declarative_base()

class Bar(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'Bar'
    _id = Column('_id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column('email', String(50))
```

---

**File `stack29B.py`** (equivalent to your `someinterface.py`):

```
class SomeInterface(object):
    def some_method(self):
        print "hellou"
```

---

**File `stack29C.py`** (equivalent to your `modelaugmented.py`):

```
from stack29A import Bar
from stack29B import SomeInterface

class BarAugmented(Bar, SomeInterface):
    pass
```

---

**File `stack29D.py`** (like a kind of `main.py`: table creator and sample):

```
from stack29C import BarAugmented
from stack29A import session, engine, DeclarativeBase

if __name__ == "__main__":
    DeclarativeBase.metadata.create_all(engine)
    b1 = BarAugmented()
    b1.email = "foo@bar.baz"
    b2 = BarAugmented()
    b2.email = "baz@bar.foo"
    session.add_all([b1, b2])
    session.commit()
    b3 = session.query(BarAugmented)\
                    .filter(BarAugmented.email == "foo@bar.baz")\
                    .first()
    print "b3.email: %s" % b3.email                    
    b3.some_method()
```

If I run the "main" file (`stack29D.py`) everything works as expected:

```
(venv_SO)borrajax@borrajax:~/Documents/Tests$ python ./stack29D.py
b3.email: foo@bar.baz
hellou
```

Comment: Thanks @BorrajaX. Really helpful. Trying to figure out why mine is not working. It could be because my `SomeInterface` has methods that do session queries (but it still inherits from object).

Comment: I'll figure it out and report back.

Comment: Yeah, that's odd... that wouldn't alter the metaclass... Yeah, let me know. I'm curious myself now **:-)**

Comment: very embarrasing. The problem was in importing. What I should have done was write: `from SomeInterface import SomeInterface`.  I'm relatively new to Python.

Comment: Glad I was helpful somehow... (somehow... because I hope I helped figuring out the problem, not that I solved the problem) **:-D**

Comment: definitely helped figure it out. Also taught me I shouldn't be inheriting from multiple table classes.