# MetaClass Conflict: Base Class and Derived class have different metaclass

Tags: python, inheritance, metaclass

```
class AbstractBaseClass:
  __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

  @abc.abstractmethod
  def someMethod()

class DerviedClass(AbstractBaseClass):
  __metaclass__ = Singleton

  def someMethod():
    """dosomething"""
    pass

#defines singleton design pattern not defining for sake of simplicity 
class Singleton:
```

(see here [Creating a singleton in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python))

I see following error

> TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
>       metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

This seems to be becauase base class and derived class have two different metaclass defination. how do i go around this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Triple inheritance causes metaclass conflict... Sometimes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557407/triple-inheritance-causes-metaclass-conflict-sometimes)

Comment: How to solve: Read - http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~micheles/python/metatype.html

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33364070/python-implementing-singleton-as-metaclass-but-for-abstract-classes.