# How to Make a Singleton Class inherit from an Abstract Class

Tags: python

I have defined my singleton metaclass as follows:

```
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]
```

Then I defined another class that I want to work as an interface for my implementations:

```
class ClientBase(metaclass = abc.ABCMeta):
    @classmethod
    def __subclasshook__(cls, subclass):
        return (hasattr(subclass, 'logout') and
                callable(subclass.logout) or
                NotImplemented)

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def logout(self, refresh_token: str):
        """
            Logout a user from OIDC Provider.
        :param refresh_token: refresh token to invalidate
        :return:
        """
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Now I define one implementation of my `ClientBase` interface as follows:

```
class ClientImplementation1(ClientBase, metaclass = Singleton):
    installed: bool
    client_secret: str

    def __init__(self):
        ...
```

However when I start my application I get an Error on the `ClassImplementation1` defintion:

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

Can anyone help me find a way to have singleton class that can inherit from a base abstract class?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sounds like you need a common base class above "Singleton" and "abc.ABCMeta"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Triple inheritance causes metaclass conflict... Sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6557407/triple-inheritance-causes-metaclass-conflict-sometimes)

Comment: Welcome to why metaclasses should not be overused: they don't compose easily. I would think hard about why you think you need a `Singleton` metaclass at all. See https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/202204/singleton_is_a_bad_idea.html.

Comment: Thanks A lot guys! really insightful links there :)

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are trying to subclass two separate meta-classes, `Singleton` and `abc.ABCMeta`. This latter is a transitive subclass, because you're subclassing `ClientBase`.

If you can get away with it, `ClientBase` should also subclass `Singleton`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7314847/442945).